# Vaadin-> BeanFieldGroup scroll page to improperly filled field

Tags: hibernate, vaadin, bean-validation

I have a Bean

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_beans1")
public class Bean1 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @NotNull(message = "empty")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 200)
    private String a00_01 = "";
...}
```

In my layout i'm binding it with BeanFieldGroup

```
final BeanFieldGroup<Bean1> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<Bean1>(Bean1.class);
....
 vl00.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind(((MyUI) MyUI.getCurrent()).stringResource.getString("00.01"), "a00_01", TextField.class));
```

And submit it with:

```
 Button submit = new Button(((MyUI) MyUI.getCurrent()).stringResource.getString("submit"));
    submit.setSizeUndefined();
    submit.addClickListener(event -> {
                try {
                    binder.commit();
((MyUI) MyUI.getCurrent()).bean1Service.insert(binder.getItemDataSource().getBean());
}
catch (FieldGroup.CommitException e)
{ /*here i need to scroll to unproperly filled field**/}}
```

All works fine, bean validating works properly and improperly filled fields marked corresponding to my style (for example red frame). 
BUT!
My question is: is there mechanism for **detecting** and **scrolling** page to improperly filled fields?

PS: I'm using hibernate-validator.4.3.2.Final, Vaadin 7.5.6,

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information about invalid fields could be obtain from exception object:

```
} catch (FieldGroup.CommitException e) {
    String invalidFieldsNames = e.getInvalidFields().keySet().stream().map(Component::getCaption).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    Notification.show("Invalid fields: ", invalidFieldsNames, Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

You could use @HenriKerola answer to scroll the view to any invalid field.

Simple solution: First you can save all yours fields in some container and in `catch` you should find captions of invalid fields and then scroll to right component using your own mapping (obtain from container). Or choose any:

```
getUI().scrollIntoView(e.getInvalidFields().keySet().iterator().next());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the the component instance you want scroll to, you could use the `scrollIntoView` method on the `UI` class:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();

...

getUI().scrollIntoView(textField);
```

Comment: thanks, it was helpfully. but main problem is how to detect  "improperly filled fields"